# Mock child component callback with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, callback, enzyme

Using Jest and Enzyme, how can I mock a Child component's callback function to return a specific value, and then test its effect elsewhere in the Parent component?

In the example below, when the `Child` callback `onSelectionChange` occurs, it changes the state, which enables the `Button` which was previously disabled by passing that state value in props `<Button disabled={disableButton} />`

I want to mock the Child component to return false from onSelectionChange and test that the Button disabled prop has changed.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
import Child from "./Child";

const Parent = () => {
  const [disableButton, setDisableButton] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button disabled={disableButton} />
      <Child onSelectionChange={(isDisabled) => setDisableButton(isDisabled)} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Comment: You can't, and you probably shouldn't. Unit test the `Child` and `Button` components separately based on what you can provide via props. Then if necessary, write an integration test for the `Parent` where you trigger the events in the child that will actually set the state for the button and assert on that result.

Comment: What testing library are you using? react-testing-library or enzyme?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I am using Enzyme. I updated the question to include this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mock any component. You can use [.invoke(invokePropName)(...args) => Any](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/invoke.html#invokeinvokepropnameargs--any) API invokes a function prop. You don't even have to care about how to trigger the `onSelectionChange`. Just invoke it with a correct argument, you need to make sure about this.

E.g.

`Parent.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from './Button';
import Child from './Child';

const Parent = () => {
  const [disableButton, setDisableButton] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button disabled={disableButton} />
      <Child onSelectionChange={(isDisabled) => setDisableButton(isDisabled)} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

`Child.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

const Child = ({ onSelectionChange }) => {
  return <div>Child</div>;
};

export default Child;
```

`Button.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = (props) => {
  return <button {...props}>click me</button>;
};
```

`Parent.test.tsx`:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import Button from './Button';
import Child from './Child';
import Parent from './parent';

describe('71713192', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Parent />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Button).exists()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.find(Button).prop('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
    wrapper.find(Child).invoke('onSelectionChange')(false);
    expect(wrapper.find(Button).prop('disabled')).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71713192/parent.test.tsx (9.794 s)
  71713192
    ✓ should pass (26 ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |    87.5 |      100 |      50 |    87.5 |                   
 Button.tsx |      75 |      100 |       0 |      75 | 4                 
 Child.tsx  |      75 |      100 |       0 |      75 | 4                 
 parent.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.596 s, estimated 12 s
```

package version:

```json
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3"
```